# Print array element from core data fetch swift 3

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I want to get an attribute from an array that I've fetched. However, I keep getting an `index out of range` error when I try something like this `txt_name.text = user[1].name!`. `admin_info` is a global variable that contains data from another view controller.

```
var admin_info = String()
var user:[Users] = []



@IBOutlet weak var txt_name: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txt_password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txt_email: UITextField!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let query:NSFetchRequest<Users> = Users.fetchRequest()
    let key = admin_info

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name matches[c] %@", key)
    query.predicate = predicate

    do{
        user = try context.fetch(query)


    }catch{
        print("error")
    }





}
```

Comment: Add the line `print(user.count)` after the fetch to see how many items are in the array. By the way `var user:[Users] = []` is very confusing. Actually the variable is supposed to be plural as the type is an array and the `Entity` is supposed to be singular : `var users = [User]()`

Comment: I get one item.

Comment: Then write `user[0].name!`. Indices are zero-based.

Comment: thank you! but I'm confused how the array can save all in index 0?

Comment: Obviously there is only one record matching the predicate.